# Is this possible to render youtube link with iframe on Twitter?

Tags: iframe, twitter, youtube

Well, try this on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SYFsw/8/) :

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?url=      http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vabnZ9-ex7o" style="width:100px; height:32px;"></iframe>
```

when you OPEN the page you will see "0" on twitter. But, if you "run it" (on fiddle) it will show "24". Why? And How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To me is seems like a connection issue. As you click the fiddle the first time, you get the same behavior as you experience on Twitter. However, when you click run to update, it works the way it should.

... and what exactly do you mean by *OPEN*?

edit:

The IFrame uses the referral url. If you take a look at JSFiddle, the counter links to how many have shared the page where the IFrame is **present**. Instead of the YouTube url you provide using the src attribute.

This makes sense when you think of the actual use of the Tweet-button.
But it is still a bit odd, that the count it shows on JSFiddle refers to the YouTube link you provided and not JSFiddle.

However, if you do remove the YouTube link you can in fact see the counter change to how many who's shared JSFiddle's display page.

This confirms, that providing a external source to the IFrame is not a decent way of making this work.
If this is necessary, the button must be created using the anchor element instead of using IFrame.

See this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button